# Flash Builder - Internal Build Error / Classes Must Not Be Nested

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I've been working on a Flash Builder project for about a week and occasionally encounter one of these two errors when I build:

```
An internal build error has occurred. See the error log for more information.

1131: Classes must not be nested.
```

A quick Project > Clean fixes things up.  When I opened my project this morning and tried to build it, I received the internal build error again.  This time, however, Project > Clean results in 5 separate "Classes must not be nested" errors, all pointing to my main class declaration.

Running Project > Clean again leads back to the internal build error.  If I Clean again, I get the 5 class errors again, and so on.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6, Flex 4.6, and AIR 3.5.  I haven't made any changes to my codebase since yesterday.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: You can try to build your app with ant task to see if problem lies withing flash builder or in your project. If ant task will run successfully, then you have to double-check your project settings like sdk version, referenced libs and sources and so on. If that doesn't help, you can try delete and import project again. And finally reinstalling flash builder.

Comment: do you use the `include` directive anywhere?

Comment: Also, what does the error log say? I don't use flash builder for AS3 projects but I have used eclipse and I never really cared for their "logs"

Comment: @Ronnie I'm not using the include directive anywhere.  The error log says "Uncaught exception in compiler."  Maybe I should look into using eclipse.

Comment: If you are working on a large project, you might be running out of Java heap space. I always have to [increase](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/09/improving-flash-builders-performance.html) that on big projects. I use `-Xmx1024m` or `-Xmx768m`

Comment: @user1875642 Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm working on an iOS/Android project, not sure how that complicates the build process.  I will look into it, hopefully an easier solution comes up though!

Comment: @SunilD. I actually configured this previously, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @ced flash builder, last I used it, is built from eclipse. I was just saying the debug in eclipse isn't usually very descriptive...which looks like that is still true lol

Comment: FlashBuilder just does this every once in a while and as far as I know there's nothing you can do about it (short of switching to an IDE that _works_). The only "solution" that worked for me was deleting the project (not the code, but make sure every file related to FB is gone) and recreating it from scratch.

Comment: what @RIAstar worked for me although I did it a hair different.  I deleted the .metadata folder and re-imported the projects into the workspace.  Cleared up.

Comment: deleting the workspace is usually my first response to (far too regular) FB issues

Comment: @RIAstar et al, thanks for the tip.  It looks like this sorted things up for me.  Much appreciated!

Comment: what i do in such a situation is clean -> restart Flash Builder -> another clean and the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with flashb uilder 4.6,
when i try to compile the app out of the blue it says 
"flash builder internal build error has occurred see the error log for more information"

to resolve this you have to check the compiler arguments 
when this happens you wont be able to go to compiler argumnts GUI, you have to edit it in .actionScriptProperties file

remove -local and local names save the file and try to compile you would not get the error

to put back the local you have to rephrase the local as follows 
-locale=en_US,us_EN

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove all swc references from the project's compiler settings, then re-insert them.